# Getting multiple tables with single db call in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-optimization

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and Entity framework. Previously I used to work with ADO.NET Datatables and DataSets. So in scenarios like getting multiple tables from database in single call, I used to use DataSet. e.g.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpTest]
As
Begin

    Select * from Table1
    Select * from Table2

End
```

And on C#, I used to do

```
Dataset ds = DAL.GetDataSetBySp("SpTest");
Datatable dt1 = ds.Tables["Table1"];
Datatable dt2 = ds.Tables["Table2"];
```

Now If I want multiple tables with Entity Framework in Single Db Call, How can I do it?

Comment: The answer is simple: you can't. There's nothing like NHibernate's multi query in EF. But may I ask what you'd need for? Maybe your problem can be solved in a different way.

Comment: In my application, I have a Dashboard on home page. That is actually the summary of the whole application. Data is coming from different tables. Some tables are related to each other and some are not related to each other. The problem I have is with those tables which does not have any relationship with each other.

Comment: If you can squeeze the data of each table into the same row structure the closest you can get is using `Union`.

Comment: I tried to do that but unfortunately that is not an option. :(

Comment: I think now I have to make multiple DB Calls and set data in ViewModel and then pass it to View.

Comment: Looks like that's the only option.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this but there should be relationship in tables:

```
public class Table1
{
 [Key]
 public int IDCol{ get; set; }
 public string Col2{ get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
 [Key]
 public int IDCol2{ get; set; }
 public int IDCol{ get; set; }
 public string Col3{ get; set; }
}

public class JoiningTable
{
  public int IDCol1{ get; set; }
  public int IDCol2{ get; set; }
  public string Col2 { get; set; }
  public string Col3 { get; set; }
}

public List<JoiningTable> GetData()
{
 List<JoiningTable> bothTablesData =
      from t in Table1
      join t2 in Table2
      on t.IDCol equals t2.IDCol1 
      select new { IDCol1 = t.IDCol, Col3 = t2.Col3, Col2 = t.Col2 }.ToList<JoiningTable>();

  return bothTablesData;
}
```

Comment: If there is a relationship between the two tables then there is no problem at all. Even you don't have to create a Joining Table. I am asking about tables with no relationship.